# Are other Joomla users having problems with the Pay Later options?

Tags: joomla, paylater

This was reported as fixed in either 4.7.8 or 4.7.9, but has not worked for me on a Joomla site since 4.7.10 at least.   I've had to revert to creating two separate menu items for membership, one with Pay Later, and one with credit card processing in order to provide a method of payment for those who do not wish to use PayPal or any online payment system.

Now that its time for the annual convention, I've had to create two separate events to allow for the same issue.

I reported this back in February on JIRA as CRM-20057, but nothing has been done and evidently there has been no verification of the issue.  I can't test this on the Joomla demo site as the Joomla demo is running 4.6.18, and also shows other issues.

So ... IS anyone else having problem with Pay Later ???

AND ... WHY can't someone update the Joomla demo to the latest 4.7 release so we can verify whether its a local issue or not.

Comment: there is a joomla channel at chat.civicrm.org: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/joomla

Comment: What is your payment processor >

Comment: PayPal Standard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to say Joomla is a second rate citizen, but it is by far, the least used cms of the three big ones, by people that use CiviCRM. It is the only one I use on a regular basis, so don't get me wrong, I'm not talking it down. I think the answer though is basically going to come down to if you what the demo site updated, you are going to need to ask how you can update it for others to be able to use. I tend to find that, while there are a could of us that use Joomla a lot and try to support it, if I want an integration with Joomla or a feature or whatever, I need to own that and make it happen.

As for the pay later, I don't think I've used that in 4.7, but I do have it installed, so if I can test something out, I'd be happy to. even if you just wanted me to create a blank Joomla 3.7 (just dropped today) and install the latest CiviCRM for you to be able to test on, I'd be willing to do that. In MatterMost, you can reach me @rtobias81, or just comment here and eventually I'll get an alert.

Comment: Thanks Randy for the offer.  I have a site where I do testing also, but in order for some to believe that it actually happens, you need to make it reproducible so others can do it and see it for themselves.  

I tend to agree about Joomla being the 'red headed' stepchild of the three platforms it can be used on.

Comment: As I used to be a red headed child (not step), that isn't always bad. In all seriousness, though, there are reasons for everything. It is good to be able to test to confirm on the demo site, our problem is that due to the nature of Joomla, there is an issue with getting buildkit working correctly, and that is what is causing the delay in getting the Joomla demo site updated. We are trying to resolve this issue, and will be discussing it some at the upcoming CiviCon St. Louis, so this is definitely not a forgotten or ignored issue; just a difficult one to deal with.

Comment: I had forgotten about this 'conversation' over the past few months.   Has anything been decided on how to maintain the J! demo site?   If you need someone to do the updates, I could volunteer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope having this same problem on Drupal and civi as well.
civi 4.7.16 and Drupal 7.52
I had to turn off PAyLater - 
I am using stripe as well